# Eclipse missing require source folder 'gen'

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in Android, so when I clone my repo and try to build my app there are issue as on the picture above:

[image]

I also Cleaned the projects. But it did not help me. One more strange issue - I have this error only on Mac computer. On Windows 7 everything works fine and gen folder is generated automatically.

Comment: You need to download android sdk level 17 use android sdk manager for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit eclipse preferences and select the required android-sdk folder.

Even if it does not work, then you need to download android sdk level 17, then it will work.

Steps to download sdk:-

1. Select Window menu > Android SDK Manager
2. Select the packages as shown in image:-
3. Click install packages.
4. Accept the license agreement
5. Click install.[image: Please refer this image.]

Comment: how can I download it?

Comment: this caused more problems for me. I went from 5 errors to 42 o_O

Answer (score -1):

import project into eclipse (File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace)
in Eclipse,

Manually create gen folder and add it as source folder (right click on your project, Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add folder)

Clean your project, you suppose to get R.java generated

change in res/values/styles.xml: commented out the following:

```
<style name="iWindowTitleBackground" parent="android:WindowTitleBackground">    
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/title_bar</item>        
</style>
```

In res/values/themes.xml: comment out the following:

```
<item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/iWindowTitleBackground</item>
```

Then do a Project -> Clean, you should get R.java generated.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set your android compiler version.

1. Right click on your project.
2. Select android tab.
3. In android tab select android version to run your project.